# How can I make UIViewController pop Swift SWRevealViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have this app, which has profile page. I have `mainview` in `storyboard`, `tableview`, and profile view.

When I go to profile view I want to be able to go back to mainview so I try something like this

[image: This is How Storyboard Looks]

```
class ProfileViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UINavigationBarDelegate{

var bar: UINavigationBar!

override func viewDidLoad(){
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
    bar = createBar();
}
func createBar() -> UINavigationBar{
    let bar = UINavigationBar(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.frame.size.width,60))
    bar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 26/255, green: 53/255, blue: 72/255, alpha: 1.0)
    bar.delegate = self
    let navigationItem = UINavigationItem()
    navigationItem.title = "Profile"
    let leftButton  = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "goBack:")
    let rightButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Edit", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain,target: self, action: nil)
    leftButton.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    rightButton.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    //bar.tittleTextAttributes = [UITextAttributeTextColor: UIColor.whiteColor()]
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftButton
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton
    bar.items = [navigationItem]
    self.view.addSubview(bar)
    return bar;
}
func goBack(sender: UIBarButtonItem!){
    if let navController = self.navigationController{
        navController.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
    }
}
}
```

I'm using `SWRevealViewController`.

Answer (score 0):

Embed your Reveal View Controller in the UINavigationController.

Right now, the BackTable View Controller and the ProfileView Controller are not in Navigation Controller's hierarchy. Also, your segues should be push segues for this to work. Don't use modal segues.

Follow this simple tutorial for more clarity: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-from-scratch-with-swift-navigation-controllers-and-view-controller-hierarchies--cms-25462

Comment: can you tell me how?

Answer (score 0):

First Embed RevealViewController in the UINavigation

```
navigationController!.popToViewController(navigationController!.viewControllers[0], animated: false)
```

Comment: how do i embed revealviewcontroller? im trying but it keeps making navigation bar, that i dont want, maybe i have to do it programmaticaly but i don't know how, it has been 2 days but i can't do it

Comment: yeah so i somehow managed to add back button but i cant delete the navigation bar and thats my problem now